# lightdm won't start after bumblebee install

Tags: boot, nvidia, lightdm, bumblebee

On an Asus rog with GT960M graphic card running Lubuntu 15.10, 
I installed bumblebee (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) which rebooted fine. Then I updated the nvidia driver by 
sudo apt-get nvidia-352-updates nvidia-settings
Then tried running the recommended sudo optirun nvidia-settings
which returned an error so I did the modifications manually. By editing /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

Then I reboot.
And It doesn't reboot. There is an unusual line :
"error parsing subspace pcc from pcct"

Then I can see splash screen, then I can see a login prompt in which I can login : 
I tried to restart lightdm (sudo service lightdm start) but it fails to start (because of too many start attempts).

I tried to purge (reinstall) the nvidia and bumblebee but it didn't work.

I tried recovery modes (which were at  first hidden by splash screen it works but doesn't start gui.

I tried to uninstall lightdm and reinstall.

Internet works on the computer, screen works as I can see text and splash screen on startup and shutdown. I can access disk fine and run commands.

I don't know what I can do to get it to get the GUI work again.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own answer : 
I managed to get back to the GUI by deleting the 
/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf
file which is not removed as it should have upon bumblebee uninstallation. This file was preventing drivers to get loaded by blacklisting them.